# Why does test report "[info] No tests were executed" for ScalaTest with a single specification in specs2?

Tags: scala, specs2, typesafe-activator

I wrote some very basic tests in [specs2](http://specs2.org).

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.specs2.mutable._

class MySpec extends Specification {
    "Arithmetic" should {
        "add" in {
            "two numbers " in {
                1 + 1 mustEqual (2)
            }

            "three numbers" in {
                1 + 1 + 1 mustEqual (3)
            }

            "compare numbers" in {
                2 must be lessThanOrEqualTo(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run them it seems they are running as expected as you can see below

[image]

You can see that 2 tests are successful and 1 test has failed. good.

But I don't understand why is Specs2 saying "No tests were executed" in yellow.
What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two tests were ran, one `MySpec` and the other `ScalaTest`. The `ScalaTest` was the one that had `No tests were executed`.

The output there has three sections: 1. results for `MySpec`, 2. results for `ScalaTest`, and 3. results for all (summary).

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** Remove one test dependency in `libraryDependencies` in the build and fix imports in `MySpec`.

The reason for the message is that `libraryDependencies` in the project uses both specs2 and ScalaTest libraries that may look as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.6.2" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % "test"
```

Otherwise, you'd have gotten compilation error for the `MySpec` specification as it imports `org.scalatest._` and `import org.specs2.mutable._`:

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.specs2.mutable._
```